# Grouping of element in a list given a list of intervals

Tags: python, arrays, grouping

I have two lists of elements that look like

```
a=[['10', 'name_1'],['50','name_2'],['40','name_3'], ..., ['80', 'name_N']]
b=[(10,40),(40,60),(60,90),(90,100)]
```

`a` contains a set of data, and `b` defines some intervals, my aim is to create a list `c` with as many list as the intervals in `b`. Each list in `c` contains all the `x` elements in a for which `x[0]` is contained in the interval. Ex:

```
c=[
[['10', 'name_1']],
[['50','name_2'],['40','name_3']],
[...,['80', 'name_N']]
]
```

Comment: Ranges in `b` are always going to be continuous?

Comment: yes they are, and `a` is ordered by _name_ not by the first field of the element

Comment: bisect might be of some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` and `bisect` module here:

As the ranges are continuous so it would be better to convert the list `b`  into something like this first:

```
[10, 40, 60, 90, 100]
```

The advantage of this is that we can now use `bisect` module to find the index where the items from a list can fit in. For example 50 will come between 40 and 60 so `bisect.bisect_right` will return 2 in this case. No we can use this 2 as key and stores the list as it's value. This way we can group those items based on the index returned from `bisect.bisect_right`.

```
L_b = 2* len(b)
L_a = len(a)
L_b1 = len(b1)
```

The overall complexity is going to be : `max ( L_b log L_b , L_a log L_b1  )`

```
>>> import bisect
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> b=[(10,40),(40,60),(60,90),(90,100)]
>>> b1 = sorted( set(z for x in b for z in x))
>>> b1
[10, 40, 60, 90, 100]
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
for x,y in a:
    #Now  find the index where the value from the list can fit in the 
    #b1 list, bisect uses binary search so this is an O(log n ) step.
    # use this returned index as key and append the list to that key.
    ind = bisect.bisect_right(b1,int(x))
    dic[ind].append([x,y])
...     
>>> dic.values()
[[['10', 'name_1']], [['50', 'name_2'], ['40', 'name_3']], [['80', 'name_N']]]
```

As dicts don't have any specific order use sorting to get a sorted output:

```
>>> [dic[k] for k in sorted(dic)]
[[['10', 'name_1']], [['50', 'name_2'], ['40', 'name_3']], [['80', 'name_N']]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i'm currently using your answer as it gives me more flexibility, the use of bisect is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = []
for r in b:
    l = []
    rn = range(*r)
    for element in a:
        if int(element[0]) in rn:
            l.append(element)
    c.append(l)
```

If your intervals are extremely large, consider using `xrange` instead of `range`.  Actually, if your intervals are even moderately large, consider the following.

```
c = []
for r in b:
    l = []
    for element in a:
        if r[0] <= int(element[0]) < r[1]:
            l.append(element)
    c.append(l)
```

Comment: I find this really inefficient in terms of time, as i keep checking elements that have already been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
>>> a=[['10', 'name_1'],['50','name_2'],['40','name_3'], ['80', 'name_N']]
>>> b=[(10,40),(40,60),(60,90),(90,100)]
>>> c=[]
>>> for t in b:
...    f=list(filter(lambda l: t[0]<=int(l[0])<t[1],a))
...    if f: c.append(f)
... 
>>> c
[[['10', 'name_1']], [['50', 'name_2'], ['40', 'name_3']], [['80', 'name_N']]]
```

Comment: `list()` seems to not be needed.

Comment: For Python 2, you are right. For Python 3 in the interpreter it is or you just get `[<filter object at 0x1084a5710>, <filter object at 0x1084a5750>, ...]` and cannot see the results...

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this:

```
>>> a=[['10', 'name_1'],['50','name_2'],['40','name_3'], ['80', 'name_N']]
>>> b=[(10,40),(40,60),(60,90),(90,100)]
>>> filter(None, [filter(lambda l: t[0]<=int(l[0])<t[1], a) for t in b])
[[['10', 'name_1']], [['50', 'name_2'], ['40', 'name_3']], [['80', 'name_N']]]
```